# Oracle - Update row and return updated rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have two instances which are doing same query so some times same record are picked by both instances as there status was not updated to "in progress".

So I tried updating the record first and return the updated rows by returning into cause. But I had to create variable to do that and was not able to pass multiple rows without concatenation.

But I want to return all the columns of the row and multiple rows at a same time.

Is there any better way of doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `RETURNING BULK COLLECT INTO` clause with a collection to return all updated rows and columns.

Here is an example.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
   TYPE emptab IS TABLE OF EMP%ROWTYPE;

   v_emp   emptab;
BEGIN
      UPDATE EMP
         SET EMP_PROJECT = 'RISK_' || EMP_PROJECT, 
         EMP_SAL = EMP_SAL * 1.5
   RETURNING EMP_ID,
             EMP_NAME,
             EMP_SAL,
             EMP_GRADE,
             EMP_JOINING_DATE,
             EMP_PROJECT,
             DEPT_ID
        BULK COLLECT INTO v_emp;

   FOR i IN v_emp.FIRST .. v_emp.LAST
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'EMP_ID :'
         || v_emp (i).EMP_ID
         || ' PROJECT :'
         || v_emp (i).EMP_PROJECT
         || ' SALARY :'
         || v_emp (i).EMP_SAL);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**O/p**

```
EMP_ID :3 PROJECT :RISK_ESP
 SALARY :168.75
EMP_ID :4 PROJECT :RISK_STARS
 SALARY :225
EMP_ID :7 PROJECT :RISK_ERM
 SALARY :393.75
EMP_ID :8 PROJECT :RISK_SLD
 SALARY :450
```

Comment: how to get the return multiple values in C#?